# PowerShell Pulling a Variable from a Function into the Script

Tags: function, powershell, variables

I have a Text Box function that is creating a variable **$text** How would I pull that Variable out of the function to use later in the script.

```
Function System-Box{
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$title = 'System Identification'
$msg   = 'Type in the System Name you 
are Generating Certificates for.

The acceptable responses are:
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    NCC-D

                    ICAP  

                    SCP  

                    RFK
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Press OK to Continue.'
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title,"")
$AcceptableText = @("NCC-D","ICAP","SCP","RFK","")

If($text -in $AcceptableText)
    {
    If(!(Test-Path $CertPath\$text))
    {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $CertPath\$text
    }
}
Else
{
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$Warning = $wshell.Popup(
"----------------------- WARNING!! -----------------------

You have entered an Invalid Response.

Press OK to enter a valid System Name.", #Text within the Pop-up
0,
"WARNING!", #Title of the Pop-up
48+1
)

if($Warning -eq 1){System-Box}
}
}

/// Other un-related parts of the script ///

If($text -in "NCC-D"){
Move-Certs -NCC-D
}
Else
{
If($text -in "ICAP"){
Move-Certs -ICAP
}
}
```

The **Move-Certs** function that is also being called has parameters set to run certain parts. I'm trying to use the `$text` variable to call those certain parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. You are wanting a variable that is defined in a function's scope to be available within the script scope. To do this easily, you could define the variable in the script scope.

```
# p.ps1 script contents
Function Set-TextVariable {
    $script:text = "mytext"
}
Set-TextVariable
$script:text

# Calling p.ps1 script
.\p.ps1
mytext
```

The scope where a variable is defined and assigned in relation to the calling scope determines the output result. When you execute a script, a script scope is created. When you create a function, that function has its own scope as well. Any variable defined within a scope can be called in that scope. You can explicitly choose your scope using a modifier when interacting with variables.

See [About Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7) for more information. [About Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7) also has information regarding a function's scope.